# Passthrough SATA Controller KVM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, sata, pci-passthrough

Ahoy friends.
Currently i use Fedora 31 and KVM to run a few virtual machines, including my storage machine, based on FreeBSD.
All the HDDs which are connected to my SATA controller should be passed to the VM.
Furthermore i use 2 SATA ports for Hot-Swap HDDs so passing the whole SATA Controller to the VM would be quite useful.
Does someone know how i could do that?

I got an ASRock Rack X470 motherboard, running Fedora 31 on a NVMe SSD.

Output of `lspci -n`

```
[root@localhost chairman]# lspci | egrep --color SATA
03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01)
25:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
2d:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```